# rebinding json object with knockout js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am working with knockout and jquery with asplnet mvc. I apply bindings using knockout from the json object returned in a controller. This is a applied to my markup.

If a user clicks on a button on screen, I make a call to the controller action and retrieve the data from the server again.

At this point, do I need to rebind my new json object to knockout or how is it handled?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when a user clicks the button and makes a call to the controller action, you are doing this as an AJAX postback and not as a full page refresh.  If this is correct, then no, you do not need to rebind your new json object.  You just need to use your new json object to update your view model and knockout will take care of the rest.  The way it works is as follows:

When your page initially loads, your page has a javascript object returned from your controller.  If this object is turned into a corresponding object in which all of the properties are knockout observables and observableArrays, you can get persistent two-way databinding (i.e from the model to your page and from the page to your model) after you apply knockout bindings.

The easiest way to turn your javascript object into one in which all properties are knockout observables is to use the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  Once you have done this, you then bind this to your page using the knockout applybindings method.

So on the initial page load, this can be set up as follows:

```
//load your data
var data = ... some code to retrieve your data
//convert this into a viewmodel having knockout observables as properties
MyPage.ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
//bind this viewmodel to all knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(MyPage.ViewModel);
```

Now when an AJAX call is made and new data is retrieved, when you update the ViewModel, knockout will automatically update the UI:

```
//AJAX call is made
var newdata = ... results from AJAX call
//Update viewmodel
MyPage.ViewModel.Property1(newdata.Property1);
MyPage.ViewModel.Property2(newdata.Property2);
...other properties...
...UI is automatically updated by knockout
```

Once the viewmodel is updated, the UI will automatically refresh thanks to knockout's two-way databinding.  So you just need to update your viewmodel, and knockout will automatically apply its bindings and take care of updating the UI.